# Override Ship-To Contact & Address via UDF

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have a requirement on which the **Ship-to Contact & Address** in **Shipments** screen (for **Transfer** only) will be overridden by using the location of **Customer** selected from UDF.

[The UDF that I have created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JI6SF.png)

A piece of code that I used to test:

```
    #region AddressLine1  
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
    [PXDBScalar(typeof(Search2<SOAddress.addressLine1,
        InnerJoin<SOShipment, On<SOAddress.customerID, Equal<SOShipment.customerID>>,
            InnerJoin<BAccount, On<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<SOShipment.customerID>>,
        InnerJoin<SOShipmentKvExt, On<SOShipment.noteID, Equal<SOShipmentKvExt.recordID>>>>>,
            Where<BAccount.acctCD, Equal<Current<SOShipmentKvExt.valueString>>>>))]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    #endregion
```

Using the above code, the **Address Line 1** field remains empty despite the customer in UDF being selected.

I would appreciate an easy-to-understand explanation since I'm fairly new in C#. Thanks!

**Edit:**

I managed to populate the Ship-to-Contact and Ship-to-Address fields by using the following code:

***My DAC Extension:***

```
    public class SOShipmentExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOShipment>
{
    #region UsrCustomerID

    [CustomerActive(DescriptionField = typeof(Customer.acctName))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer ID")]
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    public virtual int? UsrCustomerID { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrCustomerID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrCustomerID> { }

    #endregion


    #region UsrShipAddressID

    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Ship Address ID")]
    public virtual Int32? UsrShipAddressID { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrShipAddressID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrShipAddressID> { }

    #endregion


    #region UsrShipContactID

    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Ship Contact ID")]
    public virtual Int32? UsrShipContactID { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrShipContactID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrShipContactID> { }

    #endregion
}
```

***My Graph Extension:***

```
    public class SOShipmentEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>
{
    #region Event Handlers

   public virtual void SetShipAddressAndContact(SOShipment shipment, int? shipAddressID, int? shipContactID)
    {
        SOShipmentExt sOShipmentExt = shipment.GetExtension<SOShipmentExt>();

        foreach (SOShipmentAddress address in Base.Shipping_Address.Select())
        {
            if (address.AddressID < 0)
            {
                Base.Shipping_Address.Delete(address);
            }
        }

        foreach (SOShipmentContact contact in Base.Shipping_Contact.Select())
        {
            if (contact.ContactID < 0)
            {
                Base.Shipping_Contact.Delete(contact);
            }
        }            
    }


    protected virtual void SOShipment_UsrCustomerID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        SOShipment row = (SOShipment)e.Row;
        SOShipmentExt sOShipmentExt = row.GetExtension<SOShipmentExt>();

        SOShipmentAddress sOShipment = SelectFrom<SOShipmentAddress>.Where<SOShipmentAddress.customerID.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>>.View.Select(this.Base, sOShipmentExt.UsrCustomerID);

        SOShipmentContact sOShipmentContact = SelectFrom<SOShipmentContact>.Where<SOShipmentContact.customerID.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>>.View.Select(this.Base, sOShipmentExt.UsrCustomerID);

        if (row != null && sOShipmentExt != null)
        {
            sOShipmentExt.UsrShipAddressID = sOShipment.AddressID;
            sOShipmentExt.UsrShipContactID = sOShipmentContact.ContactID;
        }

        SetShipAddressAndContact(row, sOShipmentExt.UsrShipAddressID, sOShipmentExt.UsrShipContactID);


    #endregion
}
```

The issues I’m facing now:

1. Once the document has been saved and I switched to another document, I am unable to access back the previous document that has been saved and it returns below errors:
   [ShipAddressID - Specified cast is not valid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQOgj.png)
   [ShipContactID - Specified cast is not valid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnrIn.png)
2. If the selected Customer ID doesn’t have any data in SOShipmentAddress or SOShipmentContact, then it won’t allow me to select the customer. Ideally, I should be able to select the customer and the fields should be auto populated with address details from Address table.

I would appreciate any help since I’m getting really close to solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOAddress is a table of addresses that are linked to SOs & Shipments.  Since this data generally doesn't change very much, the idea is that records will be linked to multiple SOs and shipments.  When an address is changed for a Customer, a new record is created in SOAddress.  That way, historical data is preserved intact.  Thus, records in the table should not be edited.  So, rather than thinking about overwriting the address information in SOAddress, you should think about overwriting the ShipAddressID linked to the Shipment to either a new address you create or more likely an already existing one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on overwriting ShipAddressID. Now, I managed to find the field in Customization Project Editor on both ContactID and ShipAddressID, but overwriting them directly is a no-brainer since we have no way of knowing which ID is from which customer. Now the idea I have is by creating a custom field to take a value of Customer ID, but how do I make ContactID and ShipAddressID points to this Customer ID since for Transfer we can't select the Customer on header level?

Comment: Here is an example of how I would find this information                                        
select DefAddressID,* from baccount where BAccountID = 7017
select * from address where addressid = 100037
select * from soaddress where AddressLine1 = '11235 SE 6th St.'

Comment: Hi @Patrick, thanks to your idea, I managed to populate the fields, but the now I will not be able to access the documents that have been saved due to errors that is shown in the edit part above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would change Int32?  in ContactID definition to int?

Comment: Haven't tried this myself but I applied a workaround in which I nullify the value once it called the SetShipAddressAndContact event and the error doesn't show up anymore. However, there is one issue where once the Customer field has been populated, I am unable to delete it or leave it blank. How can I tackle this issue? I've already added [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)] but the result remains the same.